# How do delete menulets added via "Onyx"

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I added some menus via **Onyx** and now I don't know how to get rid of them again. Holding option and clicking on the menus doesn't provide an option to close them and I cannot delete the "iChat.menu" in ***/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/iChat.menu*** because I get an error message telling me that it can't be deleted because it's needed by OSX.

[image: My menubar]

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Presumably Onyx can remove them also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking you can remove Mac OS menus like that by <kbd>Command</kbd> dragging the menu off the menu bar (EG hold the <kbd>Command</kbd> key, click the menu and drag it down)

Tetsujin's suggestion also holds merit as the settings applied in Onyx can be **un**applied in Onyx by clearing the check box and then applying the change.